# "Edit" Button is not displaying in navigation controller in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, ios6, uinavigationitem

I am doing the Bookmark for my application,so i have added `UITableView` for viewing the bookmarked pages...

I have added this code to add the edit button but its not showing the button in navigation bar.......

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
self.navigationItem.title = @"Boookmark";
```

Comment: Show where you define the self.editButtonItem

Comment: You should also post initialization of your editButtonItem. I think the problem is somewhere there

Answer (score 0):

Is your ViewController inside UINavigationController instance? May be that's the issue